# How can we improve efficiency of different sorting algorithms in their best cases?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, computer-science, cpu-architecture

During my training sessions, one of my faculty asked "in any of the sorting algorithm, during their best case their complexity is supposed to be O(1) practically but is still O(n^2) as it is going to loop n times to check. so how can we improve its efficiency during best case?"

Comment: If the best case of a sorting algorithm be `O(1)` then how could we possibly improve it?

Comment: Can you be specific about the algorithms under scrutiny? Not all sorting algorithms have a running time of O(n^2). And O(1) is only a theoretical best case which doesn't involve scanning the array. The lower bound for a comparison-based sort algo is O(nlogn).

Comment: I can't think of any sorting algorithm which has a best case of O(1), they all need to at least confirm that the array is sorted by examining every element in O(n), then doing nothing else if it is already sorted.

Comment: The only case I could see this possible is if you had metadata about the input. With an `is_sorted` flag I suppose this could be called O(1) but that's typically not what this notation is used for. Are you sure you don't mean O(n)?